# .one() event.preventDefault doesn't work all the time

Tags: jquery

this is my first time posting here since l couldn't manage to find a solution. I have the following JQuery code that is supposed to prevent the default action of following the a tags in the main menu on the first click and then reset when any other link in the menu is pressed.

```
    $(".menu > ul > li > a").one("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

      
 $(this).parent().siblings().find('a').one("click", function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
```

The weird thing is that is somewhat works but sometimes it won't reset all the other sibling a tags resulting in following the link instead of opening the submenu. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   Please add a little more context to your question, such as where/when the 2nd section of code is called.  It might also be worth adding some HTML to ensure the parent/siblings navigation is correct.  See [mcve]

Comment: Sounds like you don't want `.one` at all, but rather just cancel all clicks on menus?  Seems strange to click a menu item, it not navigate, then click it again and it will navigate.

Comment: Thanks you your help. The links of the main menu open a megamenu for each link(category). On desktop it can be achieved by opening the submenu on hover. On tablets l wanted for the submenu of the category link to open when the link is pressed and on the second tab on the same link for it to go to the link of the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu > ul > li > a").on("click", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.